# How to write a JS function that converts a string with hashes and a word and output that word surrounded by the corresponding header tag

Tags: string

Example:

```
Input: "## Header" --> Output: "<h2>Header<h2>" 
Input: "### Header" --> Output: "<h3>Header<h3>"
Input: "#### Header" --> Output: "<h4>Header<h4>"
...up to 6 hashes for <h6>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following example

```js
function getTag(string) {
  const [hashes, word] = string.split(" ");

  switch (hashes.length) {
    case 1:
      return `<h1>${word}</h1>`;
    case 2:
      return `<h2>${word}</h2>`;
    case 3:
      return `<h3>${word}</h3>`;
    case 4:
      return `<h4>${word}</h4>`;
    case 5:
      return `<h5>${word}</h5>`;
    case 6:
      return `<h6>${word}</h6>`;
  }
}

console.log(getTag("## Header"));
console.log(getTag("### Header"));
console.log(getTag("#### Header"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function

```js
function transformer(str){
    let count = str.match(/#/g) &&  str.match(/#/g).length;
    return count? "<h"+count+">"+str.replace(/#/g,'').trim()+"</h"+count+">": str
}

console.log(transformer("# Header"));
console.log(transformer("## Header"));
console.log(transformer("### Header"));
console.log(transformer("#### Header"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function convert(string){
  const text = /\w+/.exec(string);
  const i = /\#+/.exec(string)[0].length;
  return `<h${i}>${text}</h${i}>`
}

console.log(convert("## Header"));
console.log(convert("### Header"));
console.log(convert("#### Header"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex

```js
 function genertag(input){
   var n=input.match(/^\#+/g)[0].length
   var el=input.match(/\w+/g)[0]
     return `<h${n}>${el}<h${n}>`
 }
 
 console.log(genertag("### Header"))
 console.log(genertag("## Header"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can count the number of hashes in the input. sample code.
```

```js
let input = "## header"

let separatedStringArray = input.split(" ");
console.log(separatedStringArray);

if (separatedStringArray != undefined && separatedStringArray != null && separatedStringArray.length == 2) {
  let totalhases = separatedStringArray[0].length;
  console.log(totalhases);
  console.log("<h"+ totalhases + ">" + separatedStringArray[1] + "</" + totalhases + ">");
}
```